# Python 3 | How do I check if first 2 digits of a number are 00?

Tags: python-3.x

When I input 00999 for example, I still get 'first 2 digits are not zeros' as an output when I should rather get 'first 2 digits are zeros' instead. I can't see the problem with the code.

```
    while True:
        x = input(">")
        if 3 <= len(x) <= 5 and x[0] == 0 and x[1] == 0:
            print("first 2 digits are zeros.")
        else:
            print("first 2 digits are not zeros.")
```

Comment: Is the return type of x = input(">") a string?

Comment: you just need to add quotes: `x[0] == '0'`

Comment: `x.startswith('00')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
x = str(input(">"))
if 3 <= len(x) <= 5 and x[0] == "0" and x[1] == "0":
    print("first 2 digits are zeros.")
else:
    print("first 2 digits are not zeros.")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must check x[0] == "0" because your input is a String.
Ex: You input 1100

```
-> x = "0011".
 -> x[0] == "0", 
x[1] == "0", 
x[2] == "1",
x[3] == "1"
```

and a String ("0") is not equal to a number(in this case: 0)